# Switch CSS class everytime user clicks - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 links with different CSS classes.
How can I switch between the two everytime a the user clicks?

```
<a class="class1" id="class1">Class1</a>
<a class="class2" id="class2">Class2</a>
```

It's just work one time, but when I click a second time, it doesn't work:

```
$("#class1").click(function(){
    $("#class1").removeClass().addClass("class2");
    $("#class2").removeClass().addClass("class1");
})

$("#class2").click(function(){
    $("#class1").removeClass().addClass("class2");
    $("#class2").removeClass().addClass("class1");
})
```

The CSS is to change the color

Comment: try to use toggleClass and preventDefault action of <a> tag.

Comment: what mean preventDefault action?

Comment: you are not specifying which class to remove - but if you are adding/removing a class, you can use `toggleClass(...)` as suggested by @kamesh - i.e. `$("#class1").toggleClass("class2");`

Comment: <a> tag default action we need to prevent right..! @stfvns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are doing the same thing. You set the same class to each tag in both thats why it only works the first time. The second time it just resetting the current class.
Shouldn't they be like this instead?

```
$("#class1").click(function(){
    $("#class1").removeClass().addClass("class2");
    $("#class2").removeClass().addClass("class1");
})

$("#class2").click(function(){
    $("#class1").removeClass().addClass("class1");
    $("#class2").removeClass().addClass("class2");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use toggleClass to switch multiple classes..

```js
$('.red,.blue').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
});
```

```css
.red { background-color:red }
.blue { background-color:blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="red">One</div>
<div class="blue">Blue</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector `"[class^=class]"` to select elements where `Element.className` begins with "class"; use `.slice()` with parameters `0, -1` to select characters in string up to last character; check if last character is `1` or `2` using `==` equal operator; set the opposite last character for matches `1`: `"2"`, `2`: `"1"` at last character of `Element.className`

```js
$("[class^=class]").click(function() {
  var c = this.className;
  this.className = c.slice(0, -1) + (c[c.length - 1] == 1 ? 2 : 1);      
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: blue;
}

.class2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="class1" id="class1">Class1</a>
 <a class="class2" id="clas2">Class2</a>
```

Comment: Best answer... +1 for you answer

Answer (score 1):

Done using toggleClass JSFIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/kameeshwaran/5puecqeq/

HTML:

```
<a class="class1" id="class1">Class1</a>
<a class="class1" id="class2">Class2</a>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".class1").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("class2")
    });
 });
```

CSS:

```
.class1{
  background-color:green; 
}
.class2{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I think @stfvns was trying to flip the classes used on both elements, not just one

Answer (score 0):

When you click `class1` once, it removes the class `class1` from `class1`, and puts `class2` on.

However, when you click it again, because `class1` is set to the class `class2`, it won't change.

You should probably do something like this:

```js
var class1check = 0;
$("#class1").click(function() {
    if (class1check === 0) {
        var addclass1 = "class2";
        var addclass2 = "class1";
    }
    else {
        var addclass1 = "class1";
        var addclass2 = "class2";
        class1check = 0;
    }
    $("#class1").removeClass().addClass(addclass1);
    $("#class2").removeClass().addClass(addclass2);
});
```